# Как получить значение атрибута content тега <meta>?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок:

```
<div property="offers"  typeof="Offer">
    <meta property="priceCurrency" content="UAH">
    <meta property="price" content="145">
    <link property="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="Есть в наличии" />
</div>
```

Как мне вытащить отсюда значение 145?
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Так же, как из любого другого атрибута любого другого тега. Вы изучали какие-нибудь основы javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу "[how to get meta data with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524585/how-do-i-get-the-information-from-a-meta-tag-with-javascript)".

Скрипт я слегка подправил.

```
function getMetaContent() { 
   var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (var i=0; i < metas.length; i++) { 
     console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("content"));
  }
}
```

P.S. принципы SO предполагают, что Вы сначала сами ищете, находите, пытаетесь и приходите со своими примерами, которые не работают. И Вам помогают. Помогают, но не находят и делают за Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого достаточно выполнить `querySelector` запрос,
в данном случае идёт поиск `meta` имеющего аттрибут `property = "price"`.

```
document.querySelector('meta[property="price"]').content
```

Рабочий пример для данного случая можно посмотреть тут - https://jsfiddle.net/adut437g/